# " Invalid token 'if' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a prototype for my very first proper game with unity. I am trying to implement a system that when you collide with an enemy the variable `battlemode` gets turned on. The code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class collision_detect : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision);
    if (collision.gameObject.name = "enemy_temp")
    {
        battlemode = true;
    }
}
[SerializeField]
bool battlemode = false;
```

I get the following errors:

```
Assets\scripts\collision_detect.cs(8,1): error CS1519: Invalid token 'if' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration 
Assets\scripts\collision_detect.cs(8,31): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. 
Assets\scripts\collision_detect.cs(8,31): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
```

I kept trying what the error codes told me to but first and foremost I could not understand much of them and the ones that I understood just did not work.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code so it's not all in a single line.

Comment: If you fix the indentation, you will most likely find the error yourself.

Comment: Please read about the very basics of the c# language. Ie how to define a class and methods within that class ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a proper code block to your method like:

```
public class collision_detect : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "enemy_temp")
        {
            battlemode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also, that inside the if clause `==` is used to compare for equity. A single `=` would assign a value but not compare. This would result in the expression inside the `if` condition to be of type `string` which can not be evaluated.

Comment: And use a `==` to compare (`=` is only for assignment)

Comment: Your code won't compile, because the type of `collision.gameObject.name = "enemy_temp"` is `string` which cannot be used in a condition. You probably want `collision.gameObject.name == "enemy_temp" instead